# How can I post data to the django database and to a CSV file

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to have an output (csv/txt) from a Django form input in addition to saving in the SQL tables

my code is here

```
def booking_view(request):
    global form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            **WRITE TO A CSV FILE**
            form = BookingForm()
            return render(request, 'booking/sandpit.html', {'form': form})
           
    else:
        form = BookingForm()

    
    return render(request, 'booking/sandpit.html', {'form': form})
```

How can i take the form data and save as CSV/TXT

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to fill in some of the missing gaps here:  (1) Where are you saving this file to: On the server? On the client browser's workstation?  (2) What happens when the view is called a second time: will it clobber a previously created file?

Comment: Saving the file on a server. calling the view again is fine, the write function is append. 

#             dict = form.cleaned_data
#             with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'a') as f:
#                 w = csv.writer(f)
#                 w.writerow(dict.values())
#             form = BookingForm()

and its working fantastically. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing `form.is_valid()`, the form data is available in a usable state in the dictionary [cleaned_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data). To access this data, call

```
val1 = form.cleaned_data['fieldNameOne']
val2 = form.cleaned_data['fieldNameTwo']
```

With these values you can then write to a csv as needed.

Comment: thank you 

          {  dict = form.cleaned_data
            with open('Desktop\\output.txt', 'w') as f:
                w = csv.writer(f)
                w.writerow(dict.values())}

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built-in module named [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), and this is probably what you could use.

Comment: Thank you - aware of the CSV module. I am curious how to get the FORM data to a usable state, then can use this module

Comment: If you're aware of the csv module, then you know it has DictWriter and [Django forms 101](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#field-data), teaches you validated data is a dictionary in form.cleaned_data. 1 + 1 =2.